# How to choose between cold and warm reboot when using the reboot command?

Tags: linux, reboot, kubuntu

[Wikipedia makes a difference between cold and warm rebooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot#Cold_versus_warm_reboot).

So when using the `reboot` command on Linux how to choose between warm and cold reboot?

Edit: Wikipedia mentions a third reboot mode on Linux. So how to choose between those three modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On x86, there are many more reboot types, and on Linux, you can choose among them using [the `reboot` kernel command-line parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) or `/sys/kernel/reboot/mode` and `/sys/kernel/reboot/type`. `reboot=cold` and `reboot=warm` will respectively select cold and warm reboots (matching the Wikipedia definitions); other types include ACPI, EFI, and triple-faulting.

A `kexec` “reboot” can be invoked by running `systemctl kexec`.

Answer (score 0):

> So when using the reboot command on Linux how to choose between warm and cold reboot?

Not in the way you want. You're doing, and are intending, to do a warm reboot.

Note that any article describing as what happens on your PC that refers to the IBM PC is *very likely technically inaccurate by now*.

In this case, that's very much the case. The situation on the IBM PC has very little to do with what happens now (the IBM PC is 42 years old). Computers have had continuously running firmware since at least the advent of ATX, which was nearly 30 years ago. So, pretty much, ignore what is written there in terms of the components involved:

Your computer's firmware (which is very distinct from BIOS, which really is an obsolete API, not the software implementing it, and many firmwares don't even emulate BIOS anymore, so that article is super imprecise in its wording) of *course* does some self-test, no matter whether you boot from "power off" or reboot through software.

So, ignore that wikipedia article. You can see the different types of methods *initiating* a reboot on x86 [in the Linux source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L654); note that the method can't really force the firmware to do something different!

What happens on a PC when Linux is instructed to reboot is that all services are stopped, file systems are unmounted and hardware as far as possible is deinitialized, and then the firmware of your motherboard gets told via ACPI that it should do a boot.

What it then does is completely up to the firmware. I've not yet seen any difference, however, to what it does on normal power-up. It doesn't even skip the time-intense memory checks, usually!

The so-called "third method", `kexec` is indeed different. But you can't generally "select" that method, unless you really know what you're doing – it's usually done during multi-stage boot processes.

What happens is that `kexec` copies a new kernel image into RAM, sets registers and the necessary hardware, and jumps to that new kernel's entry point – something that otherwise your bootloader (GRUB) or your firmware's UEFI implementation would do.

Comment: Umm... EFI explicitly supports warm and cold reboots, and warm reboots are faster (Linux defaults to cold reboots, which might be why you’ve never seen a difference). `kexec` is usable in far more scenarios than multi-stage boots.

Comment: @StephenKitt hm, as far as I know the UEFI `reset` command, the difference is mostly that the CPU gets fully reset, meaning, and that's where I can see a speed difference coming from, that also the Management Engine (or whatever AMD's name for the same idea) gets reinitialized. Haven't really observed a time difference on any of my machines! Though I have to admit I don't run UEFI shells for fun on everything I touch

Comment: I’m not talking about the UEFI shell, I’m talking about the EFI function the kernel uses to reboot.

Comment: ah, I was just assuming that would be doing the same as `reset -w` or `reset -c`.